# Prisoners, apples & oranges

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, strategy, probability

You are in a group of sixty prisoners, and the warden has a game to play with you.

In a room there are sixty boxes. Each box can contain either two apples, two oranges or one of each,  but you don't know which contains how many. When the game starts, each prisoner can go in the room and pick **one** fruit each from **two** of the boxes (including labelled ones). Then he is allowed to put '2 Apples', '2 Oranges' or 'Apple & Orange' labels on one or two of them (if they are unlabeled). EDITED: He is also allowed to change the labels of up to two boxes he didn’t look in. When all 60 prisoners have visited the room and there is at least one unlabeled box, the process starts again from the first prisoner.

After that, they will be put in a soundproof room, with there is no communication, one for every prisoner. When all the boxes are labeled, the prisoners are freed if they are all placed correctly, or exceuted otherwise.

You can simply have every box checked, then label each one with the fruit you get, but you only have a $(\frac{2}{3})^{60} = 2.7197216 \times 10^{-11}$ chance of getting freed.

What is the optimal plan to maximise the chances  of the prisoners being freed?

Comment: When you pick one fruit from each box, is there a "first fruit" and a "second fruit"? Or is it possible that, even if *everyone* looks in a particular box, one of the fruits never gets picked?

Comment: @Deusovi Even if everyone looks in a particular box, it's possible that one of the fruits never gets picked.

Comment: Interesting puzzle! Seems like it's taking inspiration from the usual mislabeled boxes puzzle, but with an interesting twist. Looking forward to puzzlers solving this puzzle :D

Comment: Why did you change from 2/3 to 1/2? Isn't it really 2/3? If you pull out an apple, it's more likely that the box contain two apples than one apple+one orange.

Comment: Hm... do you know if this has a "clean" answer? I feel like it would be very hard to prove optimality here.

Comment: Can the prisoners communicate and agree a strategy before they start? And are the boxes shuffled/randomised between rounds, or do they stay the same (so the prisoners can take advantage of remembering what they were labelled in the previous rounds)?

Comment: @fljx They can agree a strategy before they start, and the boxes always stay the same.

Comment: When the prisoner picks a fruit from a box, I assume he doesn't see the other fruit and puts the fruit back afterwards, is this correct?

Comment: @FlorianF You are correct.

Comment: The prisoners can always leave one box and repeat the rounds until the prisoners get all the box right, that leads to a 100% probability, albeit in a very very long time. Is there any flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: @I'mNobody correct except that you will never acutally reach 100%.

Comment: @FlorianF it tends to 100 I meant.

Comment: I have a question (1/2): Are the boxes distinguishable? Can a prisoner look in **the same** unlabeled box multiple times on separate visits, or does the warden move the boxes around between visits?

Comment: (2/2): You say, *"Then he is allowed to put '2 Apples', '2 Oranges' or 'Apple & Orange' labels on one or two of them."* Does "allowed" mean that they can choose not to label, or does "one or two" mean "not zero"?

Comment: And one more (3/3): *"He is also allowed to change the labels of up to two boxes he didn’t look in."* Does this mean that prisoners are not allowed to change the labels of boxes they did look in? If so, and if boxes are distinguishable, can they re-label boxes that they looked in on a previous visit?

Answer (score 7):

As I understand the problem, the answer is:

> There is no strategy to maximize the probability of freedom.

Because

> You can never be sure someone saw both fruits of a given box.
>  So there will always remain some uncertainty for some boxes.
>  If nothing is reset between rounds, you can always add a round by not labelling uncertain boxes, to learn more and reduce the probability to miss a fruit and mislabel a box.
>  But that means that to maximize the probability to be free the prisoners have to play forever.
>  To actually be free the prisoners must compromize between the risk of death and the time to conclude.

Comment: This is right; particularly, consider the strategy "Each prisoner is assigned a box; for *n* rounds, they choose that box and look inside. (They also open another box and ignore whatever was inside it.) Then, on the *n*th round, they label their box to the best of their knowledge". This gives strictly increasing probability if you increase *n*, and you can get as close to 100% as you like.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the process that all prisoners need to follow:

1. all prisoners are assigned numbers from 1 to 60.
2. Randomly, any prisoner will go into room and will examine
   Box one =  2 * ((prisoner number) mod 30)- 1
   Box two =  2 * ((prisoner number) mod 30)

   like Prisoner_1 and prisoner_31 both will examine Box_1 and Box_2,
   P_2 and P_32 both will examine B_3 and B_2,
   P_30 and P_60 both will examine B_59 & B_60
3. if selected box has no label, he will pick fruit from left side of the box and label it as per following table:

| box | fruit | old label | new label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | orange |  | 2-orange |
| 1 | apple |  | 2-apple |
| 2 | orange |  | 2-orange |
| 2 | apple |  | 2-apple |

4. if selected box has label, he will pick fruit from right side of the box and label it as per following table:

| box | fruit | old label | new label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | orange | 2-orange | 2-orange |
| 1 | orange | 2-apple | apple and orange |
| 1 | apple | 2-orange | orange and apple |
| 1 | apple | 2-apple | 2-apple |
| 2 | orange | 2-orange | 2-orange |
| 2 | orange | 2-apple | apple and orange |
| 2 | apple | 2-orange | orange and apple |
| 2 | apple | 2-apple | 2-apple |

Once, all 60 prisoners have visited room, all the 60 boxes will have right labels.

This process will work even if all boxes have just one fruit in all of them OR any permutations/combinations of orange and apple in all the boxes.

PS: It has been mentioned in comment that one fruit may not be picked even after all prisoners looks into the box. My point is: It is a possibility. not a constraint. It is like Everyone tosses a coin and it is possible that no one gets a head.
There s no restriction or constraint that prisoners can not decide from which side of the box they can pick, right?
Prisoners are at liberty to pick any one fruit from the box whichever way they want. Also, it was mentioned that boxes are left untouched, unshuffled and unchanged throughout the process. So if all prisoners agree beforehand to follow the same above strategy, they all can be freed with 100% guaranteed result

Edited:
Edited to make it more clear..
pick left side of fruit was changed to pick fruit from left side of the box and likewise for right side.
also, added PS: phrase.

Comment: There is no "left side of the fruit" or "right side of the fruit". It was confirmed in the comments of the question that "Even if everyone looks in a particular box, it's possible that one of the fruits never gets picked".

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, I agree and I know.  It is a possibility not a constraint.  It is like Everyone tosses a coin and it is possible that no one gets a head.  There s no restriction or constraint that prisoners can not decide from which side of the box they can pick, right?

Comment: It has been mentioned in comment that one fruit may not be picked even after all prisoners looks into the box.  My point is:  It is a possibility. not a constraint. Prisoners are at liberty to pick any one fruit from the box whichever way they want. Also, it was mentioned that boxes are left untouched, unshuffled and unchanged throughout the process.  So if all prisoners agree beforehand to follow the same above strategy, they all can be freed with 100% guaranteed result.

Comment: not sure, why my answer was down voted.  Will appreciate if someone can help.  Could it be because I did not use reveal spoiler?

Comment: "It's possible that one fruit isn't picked after all prisoners look" *is* a constraint. It means that you can't make a strategy that makes it impossible - you can't choose which of the two fruits you pick.

Comment: If it was just a possbility, it would be no more meaningful than "it's possible nobody looks in box 1": there would be no reason for OP to say that, because it's just saying "you can choose a bad strategy if you want". So instead, the intended interpretation is that it's *not possible to guarantee* both fruits are seen - that is, there's no way to pick the "left fruit" or the "right fruit" in a box.